# Why is there a minimum input resistance?

Tags: resistance, voltage-measurement

I was looking at [this multimeter](https://www.testequity.com/products/3355/), and it says,

> **Output rate:     0.1 V/A** (use with a device having a 1 M-ohm input resistance or higher)

Where can I read why this minimum resistance is required?  Alternatively, what would happen if my voltmeter has smaller resistance?

Comment: That is not a multimeter but a DC to 50 MHZ current probe. It makes that statement to be sure the device used to measure the output does not load it down and cause errors in the readings. That is a partial answer at best.

Comment: Also this **current probe** isn't designed to be used with a voltmeter, I see this as the probe has a BNC connection. It is designed to work with and connect to an **oscilloscope**. Sure, an oscilloscope is also a voltmeter. Not all voltmeters have an input impedance of more than 1 M ohm (usually DVMs do but analog voltmeteres might not). Nearly all oscilloscopes have a 1 Mohm input impedance.

Comment: That's indeed what the datasheet says: "Wide-band current probe allows direct input to oscilloscope or the Memory Recorder."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read it here:
It's not a multimeter, it's a current probe.
You connect it to a multimeter in order to see its output voltage, which is a measure of the current that you are measuring with the probe.
So as the output voltage rises with \$ 0.1 \, V \$ for every Ampere (\$ A \$) it measures, it also has an output impedance which causes the voltage to decrease if you draw a current from the output.
That's why they advise you to take a multimeter with an input impedance of at least \$ 1 \, M\Omega \$.